# Codeigniter session strange behavior

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, phpmyadmin

I am storing a different session like id, type, isloggedin and lastly comp_city where I store a name of city to comp_city session..

For example I stored 'San Francisco' to the session comp_city and it was successful and now I redirected to another page and I want to use comp_city's value but the strange thing is instead of having 'San Francisco' as my value it gives me 'img'. What would be the problem? Is it because I've used too many session?

```
public function index($city='', $error=null)
{       
    if($city == '')
    {
        $city = 'San Francisco';
        $this->session->set_userdata(array('compcity' => $city));
    }else if($city)
    {
        $city = urldecode($city);
        $this->session->set_userdata(array('compcity' => $city));
    }

     ....
```

Comment: may be your session data is getting overridden somewhere,could you show your relevant code..!

Comment: and how are you getting the session data for 'compcity'...?

Answer (score 0):

See what all session is set, to do this use following code and check your require session.

```
 print_r($this->session->userdata);
```

or

```
print_r($this->session->all_userdata());
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, one session variable returned "default" and another returned a name of a css file.

I couldn't find the exact reason, but this solved my problem:

There was a missing css file (in the "default" folder). I fixed the reference for the css file and the session problem is gone.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your data this way:

**right**

```
echo '<pre>'.print_r($this->session->all_userdata(), true).'</pre>';
$this->session->set_userdata('more_data', array('compcity' => $city));
echo '<pre>'.print_r($this->session->all_userdata(), true).'</pre>';
```

I am pretty positive that you are completely overwriting the entire session with the way you are using it.

**wrong**

```
echo '<pre>'.print_r($this->session->all_userdata(), true).'</pre>';
$this->session->set_userdata(array('compcity' => $city));
echo '<pre>'.print_r($this->session->all_userdata(), true).'</pre>';
```